# Odoo remove the plus icon into Kanban view

Tags: xml, odoo, openerp-8

I am developing a module and I need to remove the '+' icon into kanban view

I try to set the flags 'create' to false but that also remove the create button

```xml
<kanban default_group_by="state_id" create="false">
```

So, how I can only remove the '+' icon at the top of every column ?

Sorry for my english, I am learning it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank to a co-worker. The solution is to use quick_create attribute

```xml
 <kanban default_group_by="state_id" quick_create="false">
```

[Odoo documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/views.html#kanban)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the template of kanban view like:

```
<field name= "products" widget="many2many_kanban" nolabel="1">
                                    <kanban>                                           
                                      <templates>
                                            <t t-name="kanban-box">
                                                <div class="oe_kanban_vignette oe_semantic_html_override">                               
                                                  <a type="open"><img t-att-src="kanban_image('product.product', 'image', record.id.value)" class="oe_kanban_image"/></a>
                                                    <div class="oe_kanban_details">
                                                        <h4> <a type="open"> <field name="name"/> </a>
                                                        </h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </t>
                                        </templates> 
                                     </kanban>
                                </field>
```

Comment: When I try that I got this error: "QWeb2: Template 'kanban-box' not found"
And that's a kanban view for my model not for project_project model